# File permissions changing on save ( using root )

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, file-permissions

Using a fresh installation of CENTOS 6.2, when I connect to the server ( SFTP mount with nautilus ) and edit files, no matter what permission the file had before, it is reset to 700, read+write+execute only for the owner. 
When SSHing directly into the machine and editing files on the command line - no permissions are changed.

The files I am editing are website scripts sitting in my Apache folders.

Why is this behavior happening? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found was to use [SSHFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) and set the `umask` as an SSH option.

```
sshfs -o umask=0133 root@remote_machine_address:/ /desired_mount_point
```

Setting the `umask` in `/etc/profile` and the ssh config files had no affect when mounting SFTP with nautilus.

Comment: Getting sftp-server to obey a umask is extremely difficult. The only way I've ever gotten it to work is via an ugly hack, like this:
http://jeff.robbins.ws/articles/setting-the-umask-for-sftp-transactions

Comment: sshfs seems to obey the umask I pass it.  My problem with sshfs is that it does **not** handle connection drops at **all**.  I have an unstable internet connection and it disconnects and reconnects quite often - when using a browser these drops are not an issue because a simple refresh after a few seconds will let me continue browsing.  Files that were mounted with sshfs however, are unaccessible, I am unable to unmount the volume and my file browser (nautilus) becomes interrubtable.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to "edit" the files while SFTP-mounted?

If it's a GUI app, it might be creating a new file, deleting the old one, and renaming the new one to match the old, instead of just "editing" the existing one.

If this is the case, the new file would be created with the default mask.

Comment: Im using graphical vi, but I observed the same behavior when editing with vi from the command line.